# Why is ModelValidation Exception is raised always though the model resembles the table in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm novice to MVC and I completely got stuck with Model Validation Exception.

I want to retrieve the data from a database table using the Entity framework. I'm using visual Studio 2012 and Sqlexpress as database server. Here is What I have done so far

Created Mobile model class representing the table("Mobiles).

Created MobileContext class inheriting DbContext.

Created MobileController class which returns the view consisting of list of Mobiles.

Designed the View.

set the connection String in web.config file.

Now always I'm getting the Model Validation Exception in MobileContorller class.Even I have provided the same Column names to both the table and the model.I cannot figure out what is really arising this exception.
Table Mobiles is as

Model int NotNull
Type nchar(10) NotNull
Cost nchar(10) NotNull

for convinience I have considered character for cost.
**Mobile model class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace Mvcpractice4.Models
{
    [Table("Mobiles")]
    public class Mobile
    {   public int Model { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public String Cost { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MobilesContorller**

```
    namespace Mvcpractice4.Controllers
{
    public class MobilesController : Controller
    {       

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            MobilesContext pc = new MobilesContext();

            List<Mobile> plist = pc.productsproperty.ToList();

            return View(plist);
        }

    }
}
```

**MobilesContext class**

```
namespace Mvcpractice4.Models
{
    public class MobilesContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Mobile> productsproperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Details View**

```
@model IEnumerable< Mvcpractice4.Models.Mobile>
@using Mvcpractice4.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>
<ul>@foreach(Mobile obj in @Model)
    {
    <li>
        @obj.Model
    </li>
    <li>
        @obj.Type
    </li>
    <li>
        @obj.Cost
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

And the Connection String in the Web.Cofig file is as

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MobilesContext" connectionString="server=.\sqlexpress;database=Gadgets;integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What the Exact error are you getting?

Comment: When and where in the code tou are getting exception?

Comment: That type of exception would only be raised if you were attempting to save an invalid entity to your database. However, none of the code you've posted attempts to save any entities or even deals with post data, for that matter. Post the code that is actually raising the exception.

Comment: In MobilesController Class. I'm getting "ModelValidation Exception was not handled by user code" at ToList(); method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on answers to a [similar post](https://forums.asp.net/t/2006635.aspx?ModelValidation%20exception), i would guess that Entity Framework needs a key - the table's primary key in the database.

```
[Table("Mobiles")]
public class Mobile
{   
    [Key]
    public int Model { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public String Cost { get; set; }
}
```